# Determining decimal precision of a floating point number

Tags: floating-point, decimal, precision

I have been searching the internet for days now and can't seem to find a generally accepted formula for determining the number of decimal digits that we can store in a floating point format without truncation error. The answer I came across the most often was:

Decimal precision = log₁₀(2ⁿ), where n = the number of bits in the mantissa.

Now, this lines up with everything I've seen with the single point and double point formats discussed in my CS book.

However, when I went to check this against the examples in my CS book, the numbers didn't line up.

The examples used an 8-bit format with a 4 bit mantissa. Given the formula above, I should only be able to store a decimal value with precision of up to 1.2 digits. However, according to the book (and confirmed by trying other decimal values) I can store a value such as 2.25 in a 4 bit mantissa with out truncation. 0.0625 can be stored as well without error. In both of these cases, the decimal digits exceed the 1.2 given from the equation above.

I can't help but wonder if there is something I am missing. Is there a way to determine decimal precision given a mantissa of any size? Does the formula above conflict with mantissa fields below a certain size?

Any clarity on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Danny D.

Comment: You probably mean *single precision* and *double precision* formats, i.e. IEEE-754 single and double types. There are no "double point" formats. If you print out 0.1, you find that it is exactly 0.100000001490116119384765625 in single precision format, although the format is said to store only 6-7 digits (do the log calculation and you will see why). This means it can **reliably** store that number of digits, not that for certain values, the stored number can't have more decimal digits (if expressed in a digital format). Some exactly representable values can have quite a few more digits.

Comment: Taking log10(2^n) as a number of decimal digits is only a measure of the information conveyed in n bits. it is not a literal number of decimal digits that can be stored. Floating-point formats with a binary radix represent integers multiplied by a power of two (which may be two to a positive or a negative power). Generally, binary floating-point numbers are not good fits with decimal numerals, and you should not think of them as decimal numerals. We can describe bounds on how many decimal digits can be converted to floating-point and back with enough precision that the original numeral is…

Comment: … recovered. However, that is not something you should be concerned with when first learning about floating-point numbers. You should be learning from a text that focuses on the properties of the floating-point numbers themselves, not on relating them to decimal numerals.

Comment: Eric, the text itself is for my intro to computer science course, so it was chosen for me. I've kind of already told myself that I'm thinking too hard about this particular problem, but I have a tendency to obsess over understanding a subject completely and not just bits (hehe) and pieces.

Comment: Frustrating as it is to admit, I'm still not sure I follow what you and Rudy are saying. If for example, a certain 9 digit value were to be stored using single precision, it could still be stored without error? (Sorry for the long text block, commenting from phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a generally accepted formula for determining the number of decimal digits that we can store in a floating point format without truncation error.

Research `FLT_DIG, DBL_DIG, LDBL_DIG`.  They are the number of significant decimal digits (as in *text*) that can be rounded into a floating-point type and back again for `float, double, long double`.

With binary bases and to generalize for OP, use

```
floor((significant_bits - 1) log10(base))
```

With `base == 2` and a `significant_bits == 5` bit signicand (4 explicitly encoded, 1 implied), this is `floor(1.204...)` or `1`.

This means with decimal numbers of the form w.000 * 10<sup>power</sup>, **all** combinations of `w` (`1`-`9`) and `power` (in a min/max range) would "round-trip" from decimal text to OP_s_Floating_point_type to decimal text successfully.

If one tried to round-trip decimal text of the form w.y00 * 10<sup>power</sup>, for some combination of `w,y`, a failure would occur.  It does not mean all combinations of that form would fail, just some.

Consider trying to take decimal text "9.0", "9.1", "9.2", ... "9.9" and convert those 10 to OP's FP format.  In the 9 range, that format only supports encoding 9.0 and 9.5.  So mapping those 10 numbers would result in 2 different FP numbers.  Of course converting those 2 back to decimal form results in only 2 different answers.  The round-trip failed for 8 of those 10.

> if there is something I am missing.
>   Is there a way to determine decimal precision given a mantissa of any size?

The value of 1 derived from the above formula is the *worst case* and the *worst case* is the number usually reported for *decimal precision*.

Comment: I think I am picking up what you are putting down. So even though the worst case was 1.204 (or 1), it is still possible that certain 2,or even 3 decimal digit numbers could round trip with that 4 bit mantissa? So by that same logic, the single precision float with a worst case of 7.225 could support a round trip for some numbers that contain more than 8 decimal digits for some numbers?

Comment: @DannyD Yes you are on the right track.  Even your little FP may round-trip _select_ decimal values like 0.0078125
 successfully (5 digits).  Note: [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) does not have a worst case of 7.225, but 6.92...  Try `printf("%d\n", FLT_DIG);`

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate the explanation!